# Attriburtes don't work in odoo with OR operator

Tags: python, xml, database, odoo

I'm using attributes to make fields readonly on certain condition, but it doesn't seem to work. I linked two domain expressions with AND operator, and linked another one to theese two with OR operator, but it doesn't make the field readonly.

```
<field name="medic_data" options="{'no_quick_create':True,'no_create_edit':True}"
                         domain="[('state','=','accepted')]"
                         attrs="{'readonly':[('speciality','=',False),('search_by','=','especialidad'),'|',('state','=','accepted')],}"/>
```

I works with `('speciality','=',False), 'search_by','=','especialidad')` but not with `('state','=','accepted')`

Comment: If you haven't looked into it yet, here is a [link](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/reference/orm.html#reference-orm-domains) to the current Odoo Documentation to search domains.

Answer (score 1):

The error in your domain is you have added an OR with only one search after.

An operator must be all the time with 2 search.
Example : `['&',('speciality','=',False),('search_by','=','especialidad)]`

in python code your domain could be write like this:

```
if speciality == False and search_by == 'especialidad' and or state == 'accepted':
```

You have two operator following each other. I think, it's simple supposition. you try to write this.

```
[('speciality','=',False),'|',('search_by','=','especialidad'),('state','=','accepted')]
```

For more explication if you split and add explicit operator the domain is like this

```
[
    '&',
        ('speciality','=',False),
        '|',
            ('search_by','=','especialidad'),
            ('state','=','accepted')
]
```

In python the domain could be write like this.

```
if speciality == False and (search_by = 'especialidad' or state = 'accepted')
```

Comment: For me It's not clear how his conditions really have to be, but your answer has enough good points to get an upvote ;-)

Comment: If you need more information about logical of domain notation. Look this https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notations_infix%C3%A9e,_pr%C3%A9fix%C3%A9e,_polonaise_et_postfix%C3%A9e

Answer (score -1):

Try the or operator twice in your code like this :

```
<field name="medic_data" options=" 
   {'no_quick_create':True,'no_create_edit':True}"
                         domain="[('state','=','accepted')]"
                         attrs="{'readonly':[('speciality','=',False), 
  ('search_by','=','especialidad'),'|', '|', 
  ('state','=','accepted')],}"/>
```